# android studio: cannot run emulator/avd

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm giving Android Studio (I/O preview 0.3.5), and when trying to launch an emulators I get warnings like this:

```
'studioavd' may be incompatible with your configuration
```

and then errors like this

```
/home/hoff/programs/android-studio/sdk/tools/emulator -avd studioavd -netspeed full -netdelay none

emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
```

In the case of avd's that I had created in the past (from eclipse), I get

```
emulator: ERROR: unknown skin name 'WVGA800'
```

Any ideas what's going on, how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

- Solution for me.

I had the same problem on my Mac and I just went to: Tool->Android->AVD Manager
All the emulators had red crosses through them.
Then I clicked on the emulator I was interested in, then pressed the edit button and changed the the API level and and selected the only available ABI (ARM).

- My musings

  - How/where to download the intel emulator for that ABI drop down, it is supposed to be faster.
  - I still can't get it to recognize my physical tablet connected via USB that Eclipse installs apks onto happily.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after an update to Android Studio 1.1.0.

I had to delete all Virtual Devices and recreate them:

```
1. In Android Studio, select 'Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager'.
2. Delete the ones that don't work using the drop-down in the 'Action' column.
3. Use '+ Create Virtual Device' in the bottom left corner to   recreate them.
```

BTW, my defective AVDs had an unknown screen resolution listed which was 
back to normal after the above procedure.